# Use of libpcap based software across laptops using Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, wireshark, libpcap

I have a piece of hardware that I communicate with using LLC packets sent from a laptop. The laptop is running Ubuntu 18.04 with the libpcap library installed.

Typically, I send a 'peek' request, this generates a LLC packet, sends the packet to the hardware and I get a response packet back that I receive, parse and display.

This all works fine.

Now I have a 2nd laptop also running Ubuntu 18.04. I've installed libpcap and copied the executable and shared libraries for performing the 'peek' operation to this machine.

When I execute the 'peek' I can see LLC request packet in wireshark and it is correct. However I get no response from the hardware, i.e. I see no response packet in wireshark after the request has been sent.

This has me perplexed. Is it possible that wireshark could see the LLC request packet, but the packet never actually make in on to the wire as it were? I find it hard to believe that the hardware is at fault as it responds perfectly when the request is sent from laptop 1.

Could there be an issue with me not having actually built the exe and shared libs on laptop 2? i.e. could there be some sort of binary incompatability issue? But the exe runs and generates the request packet (as seen in wireshark) on laptop 2. So that makes me think binary compatability is fine and the libpcap library is installed correctly?

I am stumped on this one..

Comment: My first hunch is that the building is not at fault. Even if it were, errors not erring is a bug where the error should appear ;)
What I mean is, the kernel makes a promise of not breaking userspace and glibc has versioned symbols, so the program should either crash at startup or Just Work (TM).
EDIT: unless, of course, the program depends on more libraries that may not be as riguruous.

Comment: How do you physically connect the device? Is it a wireless device connected to a shared router or something like that?